# Batch command to move directory to another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an .exe that produces a directory and a .zip of that directory.

I can move the .zip file into a another directory using:

```
move /y C:XXX/*.zip C:YYY/
```

I try moving the raw directory using something like this, but it gives me a filename/directory syntax error.

```
move /y C:XXX/Data* C:YYY
```

I am using a wildcard because the number may change at times but Data will always be there. Does anyone know another method?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /d %%a in (c:xxx\data*) do move "%%~fa" c:yyy
```

for each folder matching the indicated set, move the folder to the target. The syntax is for batch usage. To use from command line, replace `%%` with `%`

But this (the `move` command) will fail if the moved folder still exists on target.

Comment: This worked thanks! Would I be able to modify this some how to move all directories/files starting with "data"? Or does this only work with directories? and what is the ~f?

Comment: @user1224478, the for loop will iterate over folders with the `/d` switch, or over files without them. To iterare both the syntax and the problem changes. Determine the problem and if you can not solve it open a new question for it. `%%~fa` is the folder being referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a` but with full path (see `for /?` for a complete reference of the modifiers)